# C# 'Use of an unassigned local variable'

Tags: c#

I am having an issue with C# where I am getting the error

> Use of an unassigned local variable

I am unsure as to why I am getting this error, as from reading other questions regarding this issue it is people having issues with declaring variables within If statements.

I do not know if this is a very basic error as I am new to C#, but any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
private void remProj_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    string[] CurrentProjects;
    for (int i = 0; i < ProjectList.Items.Count; i++) 
    {
        CurrentProjects[i] = ProjectList.Items[i].ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(CurrentProjects[i]);
    }
}
```

I am getting the error on this line regarding the use of 'CurrentProjects':

```
CurrentProjects[i] = ProjectList.Items[i].ToString();
```

Comment: You are not initializing `CurrentProjects`.  And it wil lbe easier to use `List<string>` that `string[]`.

Comment: C# is not C++. You need to initialize `CurrentProjects` with `new` and a size.

Comment: you need to Initialize the variable `string[] CurrentProjects;` new it up or assign it null but don't just declare it without proper initialization

Comment: You did not create the array, this code would always crash with a NullReferenceException.  Buy the C# team a cigar for keeping you out of trouble.  Using an array is wrong, you don't know how big to make it.  Use Linq (Select-Where) or a `List<string>` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message saying that the variable `CurrentProjects` is not yet initialized. you you can escape from this issue by initializing the variable. For this particular scenario the best option for initializing is with the `ProjectList.Items.Count`. So Change the declaration as like this:

```
 string[] CurrentProjects= new string[ProjectList.Items.Count];
```

Answer (score 0):

You must initialize first the array to a size:

```
string[] CurrentProjects = new string[ProjectList.Items.Count];
```

Answer (score -1):

I also noticed this lately that you cannot create a variable without assigning  a value or something to it. its an Update on c#, so basically anytime creating a variable, you must assign a value to it..

so

```
string[] CurrentProjects;
```

should be

```
string[] CurrentProjects = new string[ProjectList.Items.Count];
```

Comment: You can create a variable without the declaration and assignment happening at the same time. If it's an implicit variable (i.e. var) it has to be initialized, but int myVar; myVar = 0; is perfectly fine.

Comment: @Ryan Intravia i can prove beyond doubt that its been a great while since you've coded with c#, try using vs 2015, create a project with it, let it update all the necessary features, then at the project you will not be able to declare a variable even a string variable without assigning at least a null value to it.

Comment: Interesting assumption and I think you misunderstood me on declaration and assignment. Here's VS2015, .NET4.6.1. Please elaborate how this fails:
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int number;
            number = 1;
            Console.WriteLine(number);
            Console.ReadKey();    
        }